# How to make my own primary key as id with letters

Tags: vb.net

im using vb.net ms access database the default id is 1,2,3 ... and so on. I want to make a customized id something like this 
P0001
P0002
like that. 
once a user add a new data it automatically generate the next id. Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Instead of changing the column, just format the id after you've retrieved the value from the database: `Dim id As String = ("P" & 8.ToString("X4"))`

Comment: how can i retrieve the value from the database??

Comment: @user3336219 How about googling `how to connect to access database in vb.net`?